# Hierarchical tree using ListView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, treeview, xamarin.forms

Using ListView in Xamarin.Forms, is it possible to have a hierarchical tree with more than two levels?

Comment: That's not what `ListView` is for. Best create your own widget.

Comment: ListView is for flat data.... but - yes, with the right parsing behind the scenes and templating of the cell you can make a tree structure appear in a ListView. I've done that but XF1.3 ListView has bugs that prevent this hack to be very useful, such as updating more than 1 item at a time (expanding a node) causes a crash that can't even be handled with try/catch

Comment: @StenPetrov, could you please share your solution?

Comment: @pfedotovsky it's too hacky. In essence the underlying ObservableCollection is manipulated on item.Tap events to add/hide child items. An additional property is used to keep the node's height, which is bound to a left offset somewhere, the result kind-of looks like a tree but not very suitable for more than 3 levels. Maybe with different visual indicator (font size? font size+offset? shade color?...) it would work for a level or two more